# AJAX POST data truncated

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm trying to pass somewhat large data sets over to PHP via an AJAX POST. My data is being truncated, but I can't see why.

```
var greeting     = tinyMCE.get("greeting").getContent();
...
var content = "subject="          +subject+
              "&greeting="        +greeting+
              "&results="         +results+
              "&upcoming="        +upcoming+
              "&thisweek="        +thisweek+
              "&signoff="         +signoff;

console.log(content);   //<--see below for this output
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "scripts/send_email.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(content);
```

send_email.php

```
$greeting       = $_POST['greeting'];
echo $greeting;
die();
```

This is the console output for my content variable (note that where you see formatting, the console output the HTML tag, but I don't know how to display the tag here.)

```
> subject=test&greeting=<p class="p1"><strong>Hello all,</strong></p> <p
> class="p2">&nbsp;</p> <p class="p1">&nbsp;</p> <p class="p3">This is a
> test. I am just typing some random stuff to verify that all of my data
> is getting passed correctly over to PHP. However, it seems that this
> data is being truncated for reasons that I cannot explain. Why would
> this happen. How can I get all of this data to pass correctly? It
> doesn&rsquo;t make any sense to me as I am using an AJAX POST call and
> not a GET call, so my data length should not be arbitrarily
> limited.</p>&results=<p><strong><span style="text-decoration:
> underline;">RESULTS</span></strong><br /><br /><br
> /></p>&upcoming=<p><strong><span style="text-decoration:
> underline;">UPCOMING EVENTS</span></strong><br /><br /><br
> /></p>&thisweek=<p><strong><span style="text-decoration:
> underline;">THIS WEEK</span></strong><br /><br /><br
> /></p>&signoff=<p>See you out there.</p>"
```

But, my php echo statement outputs only this:

```
Hello all,
```

which clearly truncates the rest of the data that I am trying to pas over. Why? What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Are you URL encoding the data you are putting into your POST body? It should be URL encoded.

Comment: encodeURIComponent(greeting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode the data, which you put in parameters

```
var content = "subject=" + encodeURIComponent(subject) +
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks that was it. This my first use of an AJAX POST, so I had no idea of that step. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you
I've been trying to figure this out for hours!

Answer (score 1):

You're sending with a content type of "... url-encoded" while sending data not url encoded. You need to encode your data correctly before sending it (encodeURIComponent etc)

Answer (score 0):

You just echo your greeting.

try this:

```
echo  implode($_POST);
```